this expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'b->'c
As the title says, I can't figure out why the type is incorrect. Any idea?
let separe l x = let rec aux l1 l2 l x = match l with
    |[]->l1 l2
    |t::q when t<=x->aux (t::l1) l2 q x
    |t::q ->aux l1 (t::l2) q x 
  in aux [] [] l x

This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'b->'c on line 3.

You wrote l1 l2 on line 2, so OCaml thinks l1 is a function, and then complains when you try to pass a list for l1 on line 3.

Naïm Favier has correctly identified the issue, but since it seems like the aim is to separate a list l into two lists: items less than or equal to and items greater than x, the base case of recursion in aux should return a tuple of the two lists.
let separe l x =   
  let rec aux l1 l2 l x = 
    match l with
    | [] -> (l1, l2)
    | t::q when t <= x -> aux (t::l1) l2 q x
    | t::q -> aux l1 (t::l2) q x 
  in 
  aux [] [] l x

Of course, you probably also want to reverse each of those lists to retain their ordering from the initial list.
let separe l x =   
  let rec aux l1 l2 l x = 
    match l with
    | [] -> List.(rev l1, rev l2)
    | t::q when t <= x -> aux (t::l1) l2 q x
    | t::q -> aux l1 (t::l2) q x 
  in 
  aux [] [] l x

This would also be a great place to use a fold.
let separe lst v =
  let f (le, gt) x = 
    if x <= v then (x::le, gt) 
    else (le, x::gt)
  in 
  let (le, gt) = List.fold_left f ([], []) lst in
  List.(rev le, rev gt)

Of course, all of this is really just List.partition.
let separe lst v =
  let f x = x <= v in
  List.partition f lst

Looking at how that function is (currently) implemented is very familiar.

let partition p l =
  let rec part yes no = function
  | [] -> (rev yes, rev no)
  | x :: l -> if p x then part (x :: yes) no l else part yes (x :: no) l in
  part [] [] l


